# not able to catch -1 response from socket read

Tags: java, sockets

I have a class that serves as a client thread.
in the class i have a `run` method that deals with the reading and writing operations from and to the socket.
my run method looks like this:

```
public void run(){
    System.out.println("New connection at " + new Date() + "\n");
    try {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (threadSocket.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream (threadSocket.getOutputStream());                  
        while (running){
            // read input from client
            byte[] input = new byte [200];
            int count = in.read(input);
            if (count == -1) {
                running = false;
                break;
            }

            String msg = new String(input, 0, count);

            // parse in going message
            messageParsing(msg);

            // respond to client
            response();  
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    finally {
        try {
            threadSocket.close();
            System.out.println("Connection closed.\n");
        } catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

I have created a fixed size byte array and i am reading the data from the socket into it.
The available lengths of the data coming in are 147 and 61, if the length of the input data is 0 it does not mean any thing.
I would like to close the socket when the count is -1, but i am not successful.
It seems like when the there is no data, count is 0 it just keeps trying to read data from the socket and it gets stuck.

How can i fix this problem? What am i doing wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `count` can't be `0`, at least if you trust the javadoc.

Comment: If you are really reading text, consider using an `InputStreamReader` rather than this `String` constructor.

Comment: @Kayaman Actually it can, if you provide a zero-length buffer to `read(byte[])`, or a zero count to `read(byte[], int, int)`. But not with this code.

Answer (score 1):

The Stream can only return -1, i.e. signal the end, when the other communication side has actually *closed* its output so that it is guaranteed that no more data is transferred.

Comment: @Tomas B Preusser i have tried several thing and nothing is working for me. How do you suggest to change the code in order for it to work? The other side is actually closing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce. Your code can never get zero from a read. If you aren't getting -1 it is because the peer never closes the connection.